# How to solve the creation of controller without domain in grails?

Tags: grails

I have created the controller without domain .I think because of which i am getting this error any fixes for it  The [searchHelper] action accepts a parameter of type [org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity] which does not implement grails.validation.Validateable.  Data binding will still be applied to this command object but the instance will not be validateable.

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer if you reformat your question so it's clear which part is the error message, and if you post some example code to show what you are trying that's led to this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the method `searchHelper` in that controller `private`, so it won't get exposed as an endpoint and thus won't give the error.

Comment: tnx it work for me.The actual proble was i had created an controller which is not associated with any domain.

Comment: some you explain it wont exposed as an endpoints mean?I still dont understand the actual problem for this?

Comment: @AjayShah all public (default in groovy) methods in a .*Controller are so called "actions" and accessible from the outside.  And an action method may have parameters.  Those parameters must be either "simple types" or descendants of the Validatable class from your error message - they form what's a command object in grails and get coerced from the request automatically.